# DateTime gets saved in a wrong layout

Tags: c#

When I call this code:

```
DateTime timeStamp = new DateTime();
timeStamp = File.GetLastWriteTime(openFileDialog.FileName);
```

I get a DateTime in this format:

> 28.12.2020 21:17:29

But when I save it in a config:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.TimeStamp = timeStamp;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

It will be saved with slashes instead of dots and month and date swapped:

> 06/20/2020 11:44:28

When I want to compare them afterwards they dont match. (I know that these two excamples dont match, but the layout is completly different too).
How can i fix it that they will be saved with the same layout.

Comment: you probably want to have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0       Datetime can be formatted into many many different formats

Comment: and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=net-5.0#Formatting_dates_times

Comment: `DateTime` structs do not have a format. You are seeing the date and time formatted by the debug visualizer or whatever.

Comment: The layout with the points does not only occour in the debug visualizer. If I type Messagebox.Show(timeStamp.ToString()); it will be shown with dots too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing the value of a DateTime type object with a string (representing a DateTime), you will have to format the DateTime type value appropriately.

E.g., if you format your DateTime value as such before comparing with the string in the config, you might have success.

`timeStamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss")`